# App icon not appearing on user feed at via [APP NAME]

Tags: ios, facebook, feed

I am successfully posting an image to user's feed with "me/photos" from my iOS app I develop. It appears on the feed, and also the text below that:

Like · Comment · Share · 7 minutes ago via [APP NAME] ·

The [APP NAME] is a link, and it correctly takes to the app's Facebook page. Everything is fine.

However there is a small icon just before "Like", and it seems to be a default picture icon, and not the icon of my app. (Note however that it has a link, and correctly takes to app page).

How do I change it to become the app's icon?

Answer (score 0):

you control the icons being displayed in post messages( as well as other aspects of your facebook app) on the Facebook developer page.

Take a look at: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Find your app and select `edit app` . here you can enter a display name, icons and a lot of other stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However this doesn't solve my problem, as the icon is set up in the settings, and it still doesn't show up.

Comment: I have done some more testing and found that if I post text only, the icon shows up - if I post a picture (passed as "source" parameter) it doesn't.

Comment: That sounds strange. Are you sure you have specified all the different icon sizes requested by the Facebook app?

Comment: Yes, sure. Again, when I post a text only (with message param) it appears correctly. When I add "source" (or "picture"), the default picture icon is displayed instead of my app icon.

Comment: hi there, any luck with this? we're experiencing the same issue.